# How I can get an exact integer from floating point number?

Tags: casting, scheme, rounding

I need to use `random` function with integer argument that I get from operations that theoretically can return double. So I want use some cast/round for this purpose. I've tried

```
(random (round 10.0))
(random (floor 10.0))
```

But it throws exceptions like

```
random: expects argument of type <exact integer in [1, 4294967087] or pseudo-random-generator>; given 10.0
```

I use DrRacket as interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(random (floor->exact 10.0))` or `(random (inexact->exact (round 10.0))))`

You can use any of the roundings (floor/round/truncate/ceiling).

This is discussed here: http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Numerical-operations.html
(search for "inexact->exact")

Comment: Suddenly, I haven't such function in my scheme (`expand: unbound identifier in module in: floor->exact`)

Comment: @Stas: Does this work? `(random (inexact->exact (round 10.0))))`

Comment: @Stas - Please see the inexact to exact translation section in the link I provided.

Comment: @Stas - if your hard-code 10.0 as constant, yes. I'm not sure whether inexact->exact will work with not-already-integer value, thus my assumption that you need `round` also.

Comment: @DVK, Yeah. You are right it works only with integer values. In my case I work with such numbers but they presented as floating point. Like this `(random (inexact->exact (/ 30.0 1.5)))`